# Stream для преобразования структуры данных

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Подскажите пожалуйста stream для преобразования

```
List<List<String>> -> List<String[]>;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Java 9**

```
List<String[]> arrays = list.stream()
                            .map(List::toArray)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Java 8**

```
List<String[]> arrays = list.stream()
                            .map(i -> i.toArray(new String[0]))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Как вариант для Java 8 просто добавить ещё один мап с кастингом: `.map(array -> (String[]) array)`